# parameter value gets reset and multi-value parameter doesn't work

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

Two Issues:

1. I've set the value of a Date parameter (Start Date) when moving from the home screen (Report 1) to the next screen (Report 2) as the first day of the current year. In report 2, if I try to change the Start Date to another date, it gets reset to the first day of the year. I had the default value set as the first day of the year and even after removing it, the Start Date gets reset.
2. I've set a multi-value parameter (Area) in Report 1 that collects four integers. I pass Area to Report 2 (through Join  (Parameters!Area.value,",")). I also used SPLIT (Join (Parameters!Area.value,","),",") to get the value. Then, in the data set, I call this parameter as "Select A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3 FROM TEST_VIEW WHERE ID IN (?)". But this query throws an error that the query could not be executed. I ran the same query on the server side and it runs fine.

Note:

1. We cannot reference parameter names as @area for example because the Composite Server doesn't allow that.
2. Split and Join operate on strings but my parameters are of integer type. Is this an issue?

Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in #1 about "...even after removing it, the start date gets reset"?  I'm not sure what actual action is "resetting" your parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Re #2:

Few things to answer and work through here.  First of all, JOIN can operate on integers as it returns a string value while SPLIT cannot operate on an integer as it operates on a string (needs a string to "split").  I'd suggest that the JOIN/SPLITS are necessarily complicating what you are trying to do, although they should still work in this scenario.

Try just passing your multivalue parameter to Report2 from the parent report as Parameters!Area.Value (no joins) and then catch it on report2 again with a multivalue integer parameter. SSRS will automatically handle the multi-value passing between reports and then your query should work.

Note that JOIN/SPLIT is necessary if you want to send a multivalue parameter to a SQL stored procedure for data retrieval, but you have to perform the split on the SQL side.